# how to create private subnet in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, vpc

I simply want to create two subnets, one of which is public and the other private. For the public subnet, I am allowing private Google access to be enabled and for the private subnet I am allowing private Google access to be disabled. Is this the proper way to define public and private subnets, or should I use cloud routers and a NAT gateway instead?

Comment: Subnet  is in your VPC, Virtual private cloud. So, it's "private", only dedicated to you. Your Subnet, i.e. a range of IP, is always private. You can't make it "public". However, you can create VM in this subnet, with public IPs and firewall rules that allow external "public" IPs to communicate with your VM.